# Overwriting external style JSON for ColdFusion 11 Chart

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfchart

I've got a chart in CF11 that is kind of an edge case. I need to overwrite one of the styles that's defined in the more general external file that's being referenced in the style tag. Here's my code...

```
<cfchart
      style="DMT_Styles_Small.txt"
      legend={'layout':'x2'}
      chartheight="300"
      chartwidth="300"
      showlegend="yes"
      format="html"
      title="SPRs By Origin (Open)">...
```

My issue is on the 3rd line "legend..." I'd like to specify the 2 column layout for the legend to override what's in "DMT_Styles_Small.txt" I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

I referenced [Adobe's Documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfchart) but it wasn't very descriptive, only citing "JSON string representation" for the syntax on the "legend" property. Also I'm not even 100% if overwriting styles like this even works in CF? Some clarification if this is possible with external styles would also be appreciated.

Comment: cf 10+ uses zingchart, so check out the json there : https://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/graph-objects/legend/

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% certain, but I think anything in the external style file will override any cfchart attribute.  Personally, I would use just an external style file to get the results you want.  If you're not 100% married to cfchart, you can take advantage of the license file while using a more updated version of ZingChart  (http://www.cfuser.com/zingchart-licensing-update-exciting/).  The CF version is about 8 updates behind.